# How to reduce the server timeout in Internet explore

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am developing a web application and published to a server. It's has some valid process so it's timed out in Internet Explorer and it ran in Mozilla. HOw to reduce the Internet Explore Time out.

Comment: Why bother, instead just don't use Internet explorer.

Comment: I don't think there are any browser aware timeout parameters, you seem to be having a different problem. Please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write this code in web config..

```
  <sessionState timeout="330"></sessionState>
```

even you can set it into

```
 global.asax
```

Comment: Is this maximum or not, If it's not, Please tell me the maximum time out seconds.

Comment: can you tell the maximum timeout seconds.

Comment: maximum timeout you can set for 1 year means 525600 minutes but its not reasonable to use that much timeout, but you can set it for hours/minutes

Comment: Thank you so much..How can i calculate this '525600';

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
Regedit.exe
```

goto

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > InternetSettings
```

right click the choose

```
new DWORD
```

name it: `KeepAliveTimeout`

give for example `120000` for two minutes then try if its enough.